# MS Word: Can a picture be in line with text, and appear vertically centered relatively to text?

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2010, alignment

I have a picture that I want to appear in line with the text. Since the image is bigger than the font of the line, I get the picture's bottom border lined up with the bottom othe text, and the picture is sticking out at the top. I want the picture to be at the middle of the line, so that it would stick out the same amount from the top and the bottom.

Using wrap text options other than "in line with text" scramble the layout of the text and give worst result.

Is there a way to achieve it, while still using "in line with text" as the pictures' wrap text option?

This is what I get now:

[image]

This is what I want to get (made by editing the above picture with ms paint):
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with "square" layout? It seems to do exactly what you are asking for

Comment: @smc, it messes up the alignment of the line, there are also other lines, above and below that line that also get affected.

Comment: well, then check my answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it can be done, but there is no simple solution. One way to do it is to call font dialogue on the picture and lower it by fixed offset. You would need to guess the value though. And if you change the size of the picure or font later you would need to readjust.

[image]

Here is a quick howto:

- Position picture inline
- Type space before or after the picture
- Select the picture and the space character using your mouse or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to bring the font dialogue
- Switch to `Advanced` tab
- Change `Position` to `Lowered`
- Adjust the offset
- Hit `OK`

Result:

[image]